# Creating a procedure in mySql with parameters

Tags: mysql, parameters, procedure

I am trying to make a stored procedure using mySQL. This procedure will validate a username and a password. I'm currently running mySQL  5.0.32 so it should be possible to create procedures.

Heres the code I've used. All I get is an SQL syntax error.

```
   GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE checkUser
    (IN @brugernavn varchar(64)),IN @password varchar(64))
    BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM bruger WHERE bruger.brugernavn=@brugernavn AND bruger.pass=@Password;
    END;
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I figured it out now. Here's the correct answer

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkUser 
(
   brugernavn1 varchar(64),
   password varchar(64)
) 
BEGIN 
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bruger 
   WHERE bruger.brugernavn=brugernavn1 
   AND bruger.pass=password; 
END;
```

@ points to a global var in mysql. The above syntax is correct.

Comment: Deleted my previous post. Forgot that @ points to a global var in mysql (I usually work in Sql server where @ points to a normal parameter). If you want to check the syntax of a command, you can always go to the [mysql reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html). For CREATE PROCEDURE this would be [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commands-out-of-sync.html).

Answer (score 8):

```sql
(IN @brugernavn varchar(64)**)**,IN @password varchar(64))
```

The problem is the `)`

Answer (score 8):

Its very easy to create procedure in Mysql. Here, in my example I am going to create a procedure which is responsible to fetch all data from student table according to supplied name.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getStudentInfo(IN s_name VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM student_database.student s where s.sname = s_name;
END//
DELIMITER;
```

In the above example ,database and table names are student_database and student respectively.
Note: Instead of s_name, you can also pass @s_name as global variable.

How to call procedure?
Well! its very easy, simply you can call procedure by hitting this command

```
$mysql> CAll getStudentInfo('pass_required_name');
```

[image]