# Can't create stored procedure with parameters

Tags: mysql, date, stored-procedures, join

I'm trying to create a stored procedure with the in parameters first date, last date and country

This is the normal query witch works just fine.

---

```
SELECT CAR_TYPE.NAME, CAR_TYPE.TYPE, CAR.DAY_PRICE, CAR.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, AGENCY.NAME, BRANCH.NAME
FROM CAR
JOIN CAR_TYPE ON CAR_TYPE.ID = CAR.CAR_TYPE_ID
JOIN BRANCH ON BRANCH.ID = CAR.BRANCH_ID    
JOIN BRANCH_ADDRESS ON BRANCH_ADDRESS.BRANCH_ID = BRANCH.ID
JOIN AGENCY ON AGENCY.ID = BRANCH.ID`  
WHERE CAR.ID NOT IN
(SELECT BOOKING.CAR_ID FROM BOOKING WHERE BOOKING.PICKUP_DATE < '2013-01-01' AND BOOKING.RETURN_DATE > '2013-12-12')
AND BRANCH_ADDRESS.CITY_NAME = 'Stockholm'
end
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  There are slight differences between them that might matter.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I'm using Mysql 5.5.28 localhost programming in sequalpro

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039324/creating-a-procedure-in-mysql-with-parameters

Comment: I'm new at this, so i only learnt the basis stuff. my question is how is et possible to put this in a stored procedure, were i can type in the parameters. CALL AVAILIBLECAR('2013-01-01','2013-12-30','STOCKHOLM')

Comment: Welcome to SO! As the other comments have suggested, it's best to include a really specific question in the body of your question.

Answer (score -1):

I can't make out what you are doing from your question, as it is not formatted well.

I have reformatted it so that it looks like a proper query, and made some changes to improve readability.

```
SELECT t.NAME, t.TYPE, c.DAY_PRICE, 
      c.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, a.NAME, b.NAME`

FROM CAR c
    JOIN CAR_TYPE t ON t.ID = c.CAR_TYPE_ID
    JOIN BRANCH b ON b.ID = c.BRANCH_ID
    JOIN BRANCH_ADDRESS ba ON ba.BRANCH_ID = b.ID
    JOIN AGENCY a ON a.ID = b.ID

WHERE ba.CITY_NAME = 'Stockholm'
  And c.ID NOT IN
      (SELECT CAR_ID 
       FROM BOOKING 
       WHERE PICKUP_DATE < '2013-01-01' 
       AND RETURN_DATE > '2013-12-12')
```

if this is SQL server, then the statement to cerate a basic (without error handling) stored proc would be

```
Create Procedure dbo.FetchCarData -- or whatever you want to name it
@firstDate DateTime,
@lastDate DateTime,
@country varChar(50)    
As
  SELECT t.NAME, t.TYPE, c.DAY_PRICE, 
      c.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, a.NAME, b.NAME`

  FROM CAR c
    JOIN CAR_TYPE t ON t.ID = c.CAR_TYPE_ID
    JOIN BRANCH b ON b.ID = c.BRANCH_ID
    JOIN BRANCH_ADDRESS ba ON ba.BRANCH_ID = b.ID
    JOIN AGENCY a ON a.ID = b.ID`

  WHERE ba.CITY_NAME = @country 
    And c.ID NOT IN
      (SELECT CAR_ID 
       FROM BOOKING 
       WHERE PICKUP_DATE < @firstDate 
       AND RETURN_DATE > @lastDate )
```

in MySQL I think it would look like this...

```
Create Procedure FetchCarData( -- or whatever you want to name it
  @firstDate DateTime,
  @lastDate DateTime,
  @country varChar(50))   
Begin
   SELECT t.NAME, t.TYPE, c.DAY_PRICE, 
      c.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, a.NAME, b.NAME`

   FROM CAR c
    JOIN CAR_TYPE t ON t.ID = c.CAR_TYPE_ID
    JOIN BRANCH b ON b.ID = c.BRANCH_ID
    JOIN BRANCH_ADDRESS ba ON ba.BRANCH_ID = b.ID
    JOIN AGENCY a ON a.ID = b.ID`

   WHERE ba.CITY_NAME = @country 
     And c.ID NOT IN
       (SELECT CAR_ID 
        FROM BOOKING 
        WHERE PICKUP_DATE < @firstDate 
        AND RETURN_DATE > @lastDate )   
End
```

Comment: Still wont work, i've tried something like this, it will create the trigger, but won't give me any outputs DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AVAILIBLECAR2`(in Datefirst DATE,in Datelast DATE,in Country varchar(11))
SELECT CAR_TYPE.NAME, CAR_TYPE.TYPE, CAR.DAY_PRICE, CAR.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, AGENCY.NAME AS AGENCY_NAME, BRANCH.NAME AS

Comment: BRANCH_NAME
FROM CAR
JOIN CAR_TYPE ON CAR_TYPE.ID = CAR.CAR_TYPE_ID
JOIN BRANCH ON BRANCH.ID = CAR.BRANCH_ID
JOIN BRANCH_ADDRESS ON BRANCH_ADDRESS.BRANCH_ID = BRANCH.ID
JOIN AGENCY ON AGENCY.ID = BRANCH.ID
WHERE CAR.ID NOT IN
(SELECT BOOKING.CAR_ID FROM BOOKING WHERE BOOKING.PICKUP_DATE < Datefirst AND BOOKING.RETURN_DATE > Datelast)
AND BRANCH_ADDRESS.CITY_NAME = Country;;
DELIMITER ;