# Mysql - Creating Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, command-line

Using `Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.45` (I know it's old),

file:`storedprocedure.sql` contains:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE loadDashboard 
(
    IN limitStr int(11)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT table123.ID
    FROM table123
    ORDER BY date_lastmodified LIMIT limitStr;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I've tried both executing this command-line with:

`mysql -u root -p -h localhost DB < storedprocedure.sql`

and from within

`mysql -u root -p -h localhost DB`

`mysql> *copied the code in from storedprocedure.sql`

The error I get is: `ERROR 1064 (42000) You have an error in your SQL Syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limitStr`

However, another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039324/creating-a-procedure-in-mysql-with-parameters) on StackOverflow uses this exact syntax and it worked for everyone else?

Comment: `SELECT table_id` ***`FROM (what?)`*** . . . Please edit your post to include the actual content.

Comment: In order to address a question like this, we need to see *e-x-a-c-t-l-y* what you typed in, and *e-x-a-c-t-l-y* what the response was. The usual way that I do this is to start the `mysql` command, then, in this case: `source storedprocedure.sql;`. *(IIRC ...)* But your use of `<` should work too.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Ok. It is fully updated.

Comment: I'm finding that this is only a problem when I add the parameter after the keyword `LIMIT`? This statement works fine if I replace `limitStr` with a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were using a reserved word `table`. Try the following. Works fine as tested. If you need to use an if-y word like a Reserved Word, then surround it with back-ticks. This includes words for column names and tables that include a space or a hyphen.

**schema:**

```
drop table if exists mytable123;
create table mytable123
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    date_lastmodified datetime not null
);

insert mytable123(date_lastmodified) values ('2006-07-23'),('2006-07-27 13:10:09');
```

**Stored proc:**

```
drop procedure if exists loadDashboard;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE loadDashboard 
(
    IN limitStr int(11)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE theLimit int;   -- to maintain compatibility (see comment from user wchiquito)

    set theLimit=limitStr;

    SELECT  ID
    FROM mytable123
    ORDER BY date_lastmodified 
    LIMIT theLimit; -- use the local variable for this
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

**test:**

```
call loadDashboard(1);
call loadDashboard(17);
```

MySQL [Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) ... the ones with an (R).

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer. You are going to be mad at me :| My table is not actually called `table` in the database. I was trying to use an example and I ended up using a keyword. Sorry about that. I'll keep that in mind next time I'm formulating one of these questions. I edited my question.

Comment: mad at a +1, *never* :p

Comment: @Drew: Remember, `Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6.` [13.2.9 SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), in 5.0.45 does not support. For a workaround, see [Bug #11918 SP does not accept variables in LIMIT clause](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918).

Comment: @wchiquito I found some cool question and thought of you a week ago. I need to spook it up. Some guy wanting a SIGNAL and I had poached some of your stuff a few weeks ago (pretty sure I left a comment).

Comment: @Drew: Interesting version of `TRANSACTION` and `SIGNAL` use in that answer.

Comment: @wchiquito That is absolutely the answer to this question. It looks like I am not able to directly pass a parameter to the limit string. I found the answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875238/passing-limit-as-parameters-to-mysql-sproc . I'll just dynamically create the limit string in php

Comment: you can do it with a prepared statement (a concat) in the stored proc. I mean, not that you would want to, but you could. For tricky stuff. Like [the in clause](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37996572)