# Incorrect syntax near 'var_category_name'. Expecting VARIABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a script that creates and calls a stored procedure named `spInsertNewCategory` and getting this error on the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertCategory(category_name VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Categories
VALUES (@CategoryName);
END
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km9op.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Also getting an error on the 50 that says it is expecting '(' or SELECT. This is the first time I have been completely lost on something. What am I doing wrong?

The code is supposed to be a single input parameter with no return value and I just don't know what to write.

Comment: My apologies, the formatting of this post looks off. I don't think it's supposed to look like that. This is my first post here. I hope it is at least understandable.

Comment: Add the DELIMITER // before the statement and at the end

Comment: You are using category_name as the parameter name then your query is referencing a global variable called CategoryName (via the @ symbol). Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039324/creating-a-procedure-in-mysql-with-parameters for an example of a simple stored procedure such as you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the syntax of MySQL, in SQL Server its:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertCategory @CategoryName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Categories
VALUES (@CategoryName);
END
```

Comment: The brackets are allowed, its just the `@` thats required.

Answer (score 0):

Add the DELIMITER // before the statements incase you are executing the statement

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertCategory(IN category_name VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Categories
VALUES (@CategoryName);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

If the above doesn't work Try with the below steps!

Go To your Routine tab in MySQL,
Click on Add Routin and follow these steps

[image]

Comment: Wrong database - question says SQL Server

Comment: @DaleK Before editing the question OP tagged "mysql" too, you can check the edit history

Comment: That's true. My mistake there. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Ben , Thats OK dude.. happy Coding